# Генерация случайного числа раз в час с привязкой к кешу

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, как реализовать генерацию случайного числа например от 100 и до 1000 посредством Js, выводом его текстом типа здесь число

Это число должно фиксироваться в кеше пользователя и не меняться на протяжении 1го часа, после часа при повторном посещении страницы меняем это число снова на уникальное учитывая диапазон.

Comment: Ну положите сгенерированное число вместе со временем генерации в какой-нибудь localStorage. А при чём здесь php?

Comment: JavaScript работает в браузере только при открытой пользователем страницей. Поэтому вам нужно просто проверять расписание. Как и написал Андрей - сохранить время и значение в localStorage и когда страница открыта - проверять прошел ли необходимый промежуток с того времени или нет и если прошел - то генерировать новое  и обновлять данные в LS